# How to return promise up the chain after recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, es6-promise

I am making a request which returns paged data, so I want to call a function recursively until I have all of the pages of data, like so:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    doRequest(1, [])
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).send(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).send("Error from request");
        });
});

function doRequest(page, list){
    let options = {
        uri : "www.example.com",
        qs : { "page" : page }
    };
    request(options)
        .then((results) => {
            list.push(results);
            if(page === 2){
                return Promise.resolve(list);
            } else {
                return doRequest(++page, list);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}
```

My route is returning immediately with `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`, so `doRequest()` is apparently returning `undefined` right away, rather than returning the list when it is ready. I'm new to promises so I'm sure I'm missing something pretty simple.

Comment: `doRequest` doesn't return anything ... did you mean `return request` in `doRequest` to return a Promise you can `.then` on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `doRequest` function to

```
function doRequest(page, list){
    let options = {
        uri : "www.example.com",
        qs : { "page" : page }
    };
    return request(options)
        .then((results) => {
            list.push(results);
            if(page === 2){
                return Promise.resolve(list);
            } else {
                return doRequest(++page, list);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}
```

so it can return the request, its actually returns nothing (`undefined`)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I got so caught up in the recursion being the problem that I missed the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed doRequest is returning 'undefined' since the function does not return anything.

The return statements that you have there belong to the predicates of the 'then' and 'catch', but you have none in the function doRequest.

You should return the result of 'request' which should be a promise, so your code should look like this

```
function doRequest(page, list){
let options = {
    uri : "www.example.com",
    qs : { "page" : page }
};
return request(options)
    .then((results) => {
        list.push(results);
        if(page === 2){
            return Promise.resolve(list);
        } else {
            return doRequest(++page, list);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

}

besides that I don't think is a good approach to handle this recursively, but this is probably another discussion.